# Embedded Database that support encryption for NodeJS or Golang

Tags: database, encryption, programming

Is there any encrypted embedded database (I don't care if it's SQL or NoSQL) that support NodeJS ([enclosejs](http://enclosejs.com)) or [Golang](http://golang.org)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sqlcipher can be built for mapbox/sqlite3

or using [go-sqlchiper](https://github.com/xeodou/go-sqlcipher)

Also, using encryption with nedb is really easy, you just create a crypto cipher and perform the operation in and out. See this https://github.com/coolaj86/bitcrypt/blob/master/lib/bitcrypt.js#L27